# In CUDA, do non-coalesced memory accesses cause branch divergence?

Tags: cuda, branch

I always thought that branch divergence is only caused by the branching code, like "if", "else", "for", "switch", etc. However I have read a paper recently in which it says:

"
*One can clearly observe that the number of divergent branches taken by threads in each first exploration-based algorithm is at least twice more important than the full exploration strategy. **This is typically the results from additional non-coalesced accesses to the global memory.** Hence, such a threads divergence leads to many memory accesses that have to be serialized, increasing the total number of instructions executed.*

*One can observe that the number of warp serializations for the version using non-coalesced accesses is between seven and sixteen times more important than for its counterpart. Indeed, **a threads divergence caused by non-coalesced accesses** leads to many memory accesses that have to be serialized, increasing the instructions to be executed.* 
"

It seems like, according to the author, non-coalesced accesses can cause divergent branches. Is that true? 
My question is, how many reasons exactly are there for the branch divergence? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you link to the original reference?

Comment: +1 I really want to know how a memory access strategie would be responsible for divergent branching. Please add the reference.

Comment: This thesis should be the reference. The 2 paragraghes come from p80 and p107 respectively. http://mistic.heig-vd.ch/luong/thesis.pdf

Comment: Sorry about not giving the reference. Thanks Eric very much for doing this for me.

Answer (score 3):

I think the author is unclear on the concepts and/or terminology.

The two concepts of divergence and serialization are closely related. Divergence causes serialization, as the divergent groups of threads in a warp must be executed serially. But serialization does not cause divergence, as divergence refers specifically to threads within a warp running different code paths.

Other things that cause serialization (but not divergence) are bank conflicts and atomic operations.

Comment: Another example of serialization without branch divergence would be non-uniform access to __constant__ memory.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the two concepts. So non-coalesced memory access pattern of the algorithm/code has absolutely nothing to do with branch divergence, more specifically, with the "branch efficiency" result got from the NVIDIA Profiler?

Comment: @Ben: That is correct. The CUDA Profiler docs say: `Branch Efficiency = ({Branches} - {Diverged Branches}) / {Branches}` and `Diverged Branches = branches that were evaluated differently across a warp` and `Branches = branch instructions executed`. In other words, `Branch Efficiency` relates specifically to the branch instructions in a warp and counts the instances where they diverge (some are taken and some are not taken).